# How to parse a multi-array JSON (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on a project that requires the latitude and longitude of a given address (input). Google maps API returns in json format, and I've done research and found that json-simple is the best option for my project. I have this code as well as the String output from google maps API, and would highly appreciate some help in parsing properly.
Also note: the call: MapTile.receiveJson just returns the string from google's API (linked below)

```
try {
            String jsonAdr = MapTile.receiveJson("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA");
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonAdr);  
            System.out.println("lat=" + json.get("address_components"));
        } catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();System.out.println("Error contacting google or invalid input");}
```

This is the exact string output from google's API:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA

I realize I could do String parsing, however it would be inefficient as I will be using more of google's API. I have also viewed other stack overflow, as well as their JSON website but found no examples with multiple JSON arrays such as those returned by google.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before you can get `address_components` you have to get the `results` array, then from that the first ( or any ) element, and then you can read out the `address_components`.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the solution:**

I basically made a stand alone and I parsed your JSON like this:

**First** : This is the method I used to parse the JSON:

```
public String loadJSON(String someURL) {

        String json = null;
        HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(someURL);

        try {

            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
            StatusLine statusline = mHttpResponse.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusline.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200) {

                return null;

            }
            InputStream jsonStream = mHttpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    jsonStream));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                builder.append(line);

            }

            json = builder.toString();

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }
        mHttpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return json;

    }
```

**Second** : Used Async Task to download the data:

```
public class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String url;

        public BackTask(String URL) {
            super();
            this.url = URL;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            getData(url);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

**Third:** Method to get the data and parse it. **I have made some comments for this part since it's a bit long than usual.**

```
public void getData(String URL) {

        try {
            JSONObject mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJSON(URL));
            // Log.d("JSON Data : ", mainJsonObject.toString());

            String Status = mainJsonObject.getString("status");
            Log.d("JSON Status : ", Status + "\n" + "---------------------");

            JSONArray mainArray = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            // Log.d("JSON Array : ", mainArray.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject insideJsonObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (insideJsonObject != null) {

                    String address_components = insideJsonObject
                            .getString("address_components");
                    // Log.d("Inside JSON Array : ", address_components);

                    JSONArray addressJSON = insideJsonObject
                            .getJSONArray("address_components");
                    // Log.d("Inside JSON ADDress : ", addressJSON.toString());

                    String formatted_address = insideJsonObject
                            .getString("formatted_address");
                    Log.d("Inside JSON formatted_address : ", formatted_address
                            + "\n" + "-----------");

                    for (int ji = 0; ji < mainArray.length(); ji++) {

                        JSONObject geoMetryJO = mainArray.getJSONObject(ji);

                        if (geoMetryJO != null) {

                            JSONObject geometry = geoMetryJO
                                    .getJSONObject("geometry");
                            // Log.d("Inside JSON geometry : ",
                            // geometry.toString()+"\n"+"----------");

                            String location_type = geometry
                                    .getString("location_type");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON location_type : ", location_type
                                    + "\n" + "------------");

                            JSONObject locationJSONObject = geometry
                                    .getJSONObject("location");

                            String Latitude = locationJSONObject
                                    .getString("lat");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON Latitude : ", Latitude + "\n"
                                    + "--------------");
                            String Longitude = locationJSONObject
                                    .getString("lng");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON Longitude : ", Longitude + "\n"
                                    + "------------");

                            JSONObject viewportJSONObject = geometry
                                    .getJSONObject("viewport");
                            // Log.d("Inside JSON viewportJSONObject : ",
                            // viewportJSONObject.toString()+"\n"+"------------");

                            JSONObject northeastJSONObject = viewportJSONObject
                                    .getJSONObject("northeast");
                            String Lat = northeastJSONObject.getString("lat");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON Lat : ", Lat + "\n"
                                    + "------------");
                            String Lon = northeastJSONObject.getString("lng");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON Lon : ", Lon + "\n"
                                    + "------------");

                            JSONObject southwestJSONObject = viewportJSONObject
                                    .getJSONObject("southwest");
                            String south_Lat = southwestJSONObject
                                    .getString("lat");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON south_Lat : ", south_Lat + "\n"
                                    + "------------");
                            String south_Lon = southwestJSONObject
                                    .getString("lng");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON south_Lon : ", south_Lon + "\n"
                                    + "------------");
                        }

                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k < addressJSON.length(); k++) {

                        JSONObject addressJSONObject = addressJSON
                                .getJSONObject(k);

                        if (addressJSONObject != null) {

                            String long_name = addressJSONObject
                                    .getString("long_name");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON LongName : ", long_name);
                            String short_name = addressJSONObject
                                    .getString("short_name");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON ShortName : ", short_name);

                            JSONArray addressJSONArray = addressJSONObject
                                    .getJSONArray("types");
                            Log.d("Inside JSON JSONADD : ",
                                    addressJSONArray.toString() + "\n"
                                            + "-------------");

                        }

                    }

                    JSONArray insideJsonArray = insideJsonObject
                            .getJSONArray("types");
                    Log.d("Inside JSON Types : ", insideJsonArray.toString());
                    String street = insideJsonObject.getString("types");
                    Log.d("Inside JSON Street : ", street);

                }

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**After getting all the data, you can use it in anyway you want cause it's mostly in the string format. You can just copy and paste this method and it should run fine.**

**Fourth** : On the onCreate() method, just executed the task like this:

```
public static final String URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA";
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new BackTask(URL).execute();

    }
```

This was the complete solution for this question. Let me know if have any questions for this. Hope this helps..Good Luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this for formatted_address. I type casted explicitly here. But getJSONArray () and getJSONObject() methods will perform the typecasting too.

```
// parse the Result String to JSON
JSONObject myJSONResult = new JSONObject(results);
for (int i = 0; i <((JSONArray) myJSONResult.get("results")).length(); i++) 
    System.out.println(((JSONObject) ((JSONArray) myJSONResult.get("results")).get(i)).get("formatted_address")); // This is your final options.
```